# Not able to Bind ID value to URL

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am new to `Angular2`. And I am trying to bind `ID` value to my URL but its not getting bind with URL. I am using cross domain and my code is as follows :

```
 onselect(id: number) {
        let data = JSON.stringify(id);
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }); 
        let options = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headers
        });
        var GetstateValue = this.http.post("http://localhost:34339/Home/GetStateById/?id", id, options)
         GetstateValue.subscribe((res => this.Success(res)), res => this.Error(res));
       console.log(GetstateValue, data);
               }
```

When I hard-coded my url like  `http://localhost:34339/Home/GetStateById/1` then it is working perfectly.

Comment: As per browser policy, CORS is not allowed. Instant solution use chrome extension [CORS EXTENSION](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-toggle/omcncfnpmcabckcddookmnajignpffnh?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon).  OR -> set (Access-control-Allow-origin) in your server

Comment: Hot coded via browser is working fine?

Comment: so..hot coded working means...check this is post method or get method

Comment: first pass like this var GetstateValue = this.http.post("http://localhost:34339/Home/GetStateById/1", id, options) to debug error

Comment: thank u soo much its Working

Comment: good luck ....take next move

Comment: But Tangalvali     let data = JSON.stringify(id);    var GetstateValue = this.http.post("http://localhost:34339/Home/GetStateById"+'/' + data, options)  its throughing Error as    :34339/Home/GetStateById/%221%22   it mean its a json data but v need 2 convert this data

Answer (score 0):

## Angular POST Method

```
Angular HTTP post method need header and pass data in JSON data.
```

```html
onselect(id: number) {
        let data = JSON.stringify(id);
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }); 
        let options = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headers
        });
      
        let id = id;
        
        var GetstateValue = this.http.post("http://localhost:34339/Home/GetStateById", id, options)
         GetstateValue.subscribe(
         res => {
              this.result = res;
              console.log(this.result);
         },
         res => {
              this.Error = res;
       console.log(this.error);
               }
               );
```

See my github link [HTTP service](https://github.com/thangavel28/studentlogin/blob/master/src/app/service/service.ts)
see my angular app for http post method[link](http://asdes.herokuapp.com)

Comment: if i wana 2 pass id 2 then